# How many times can a Win 7 Professional serial be activated?

Tags: windows, windows-activation

Not doing any piracy work but I format my computer some times more than I should.

I hear that there is a number of times a win 7 key can be used for activation.
is that true? If so how many times can we use it?

This is for activation of the same key in ONE machine after being formatted multiple times.
FYI : I have a Win 7 Professional Edition Key.

Does this change if it's a retail or OEM version?

Comment: It depends on what type of license you have.  In any situation the number of times you activate on the same system is not limited.  You might have to call Microsoft because you reach some sort of automatic limit to prevent abuse.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reinstalling the same, unchanged system, then the answer is you are activating *the same system* so you can re-activate it an unlimited number of times.

I've had issues with motherboard replacements with an OEM edition of Windows, but a call to MS fixed the issue.